# Find correct regex

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I'm trying to find the correct regex for this case:

- ???-1.1.0-???

I need prefix and suffix between version, ? can be everything (letter, number or nothing)

What I have :

```
static check(version: string) {
    return /-(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-$/.test(version);
}
```

THanks for your help :)

Comment: For the first, do you mean you need the suffix i.e. 1.1.0 ? "and not toto" Add clarity by adding real expected values for your examples.

Comment: No like this : ???-1.1.0

Comment: So you need to ignore the "toto" part all together? What is your expected output for your first two examples? What are you ignoring?

Comment: Yeah it is just for example, I just need help for do a prefix and suffix with a version in regex :)

Comment: You need to clarify your question by providing ACTUAL output and EXPECTED output with a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I tried to edit my issue

Comment: You say you want to match `-1-1.0-`, but your regex demands a _dot_ between the first and second number, not a minus.

Comment: And why are you _anchoring_ your pattern at the end with `$`, when you want to _allow_ for other stuff to come after it?

Comment: @CBroe Yes sry this is a point

Comment: Remove the dollar sign. `/-(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-/.test('foo-1.1.0-bar');` results in `true`, so that should be what you want.

Comment: Yes for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't `"???-1-"` still be the "prefix", there is no way to tell by a simple regex, you will need to capture everything between number, dot, number, etc... until you meet another dash.

### Breakdown

There are three groups: the prefix (optional), version, and suffix (also optional).

1. `([a-z][a-z-]*\-)?`

   - Starts with a letter, followed by zero or more letters and dashes, ending with a dash
2. `([0-9][0-9.]*)`

   - Starts with a number, followed by zero or more numbers and dot-literals
3. `(\-[a-z][a-z-]*)?`

   - Starts with a dash, followed by a letter and zero or more letters and dashes

### Unit tests

```js
const VERSION_PATTERN = /([a-z][a-z-]*\-)?([0-9][0-9.]*)(\-[a-z][a-z-]*)?/i;

const isVersionValid = (version) =>  VERSION_PATTERN.test(version);

const testCases = [
  { version: 'toto-1-1.0-toto', valid : true  },
  { version: 'toto-1-1.0'     , valid : true  },
  { version: '1-1.0-toto'     , valid : true  },
  { version: '1-1.0'          , valid : true  },
  { version: 'toto'           , valid : false },
];

mocha.setup("bdd");
chai.should();

testCases.forEach(testCase => {  
  describe("Validity test", function() {
      it(`"${testCase.version}" is ${testCase.valid ? 'valid' : 'invalid'}`, () => {
          isVersionValid(testCase.version).should.equal(testCase.valid);
      });
  });
});

mocha.run();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.2.0/chai.js"></script>

<div id="mocha"></div>
```