# Regex incorrect

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to do a regex for this string:

- 1.0.0-toto1-TEST

This is my regex but incorrect :

```
 ^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-(\[a-z]*)-(TEST)$
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Don't escape the `[`.

Comment: You're not matching the 1 after toto

Comment: How is this different to [your question from yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153650/find-correct-regex)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find correct regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62153650/find-correct-regex)

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(/^(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)-([a-z0-9]*)-(TEST)$/.test("1.0.0-toto1-TEST"));
```